# Solving warning "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observableobject

I am getting the following purple warning in my SwiftUI view update:

```
  "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior."
```

The warning is caused due to the following in my `ObservableObject` code:

```
    fileprivate func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: Key) {
    
           if peerDeviceSettings != nil {
               peerDeviceSettings?[key.rawValue] = value
           } else {
               UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key.rawValue)
           }

             objectWillChange.send() //<--- This line causes warning
      }

     var someProperty:Array<MyPropertyType> {
    
       get {
           var allValues:Array<MyPropertyType > = []
        
           if let storedValues = setting(forKey: Key.myValues) as? Array<[String:Any]> {
                 allValues = storedValues.map { MyPropertyType($0) }
           } else {
               //Install default values now
               let allValuesDictionary = MyPropertyType.defaultValuesArray()
               set(allValuesDictionary, forKey: Key.myValues)
               allValues = self.someProperty
            }
        
            return allValues
        }
    
        set (newValue) {
            var dictionaries:Array<Dictionary<String, Any>> = []
            dictionaries = newValue.map { $0.dictionary() }
            set(dictionaries, forKey: Key.myValues)
         }
      }
```

So basically I am reading a setting property from `body` var and the settings code is trying to install default values if nothing was found at the startup and the setter code is triggering `objectWillChange.send()` . To solve it, I have modified the setter code to notify changes on the main queue.

```
  fileprivate func set(_ value: Any?, forKey key: Key) {
     if peerDeviceSettings != nil {
         peerDeviceSettings?[key.rawValue] = value
     } else {
         UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key.rawValue)
     }
    
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.objectWillChange.send() //<-- This fixes the warning
     }
  }
```

I want to know if this solution has any pitfalls or there is a better solution?

Comment: The solution is a reasonable one, but it would probably be good to refactor so that the `body` can't `set` -- triggering any work in the `body` is generally a bad practice. Maybe look at something like `@AppStorage` where a default value can be read without actually _setting_ the value if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Problem is I have two paths of settings, one as `UserDefaults` and other as a dictionary of settings received from peerDevice (as can be seen in setter code I posted). If it was only `UserDefaults`, I could have used `@AppStorage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work? Yes.

Are there any pitfalls? Yes. You are setting a value in a get function, which breaks the Principle Of Least Astonishment.

Is there a better solution? Probably, depending on what you are trying to do.

As @jnpdx mentioned, you could use @AppStorage in the view itself. You could also give back a default value in the read function without setting the underlying value itself. You could set the default value on appear, or segregate this matter completely from the ViewModel, so that a provider of this collection is injected and subscribed to.

Ask yourself: who owns this model? At what stage should it be initiated with default values? Your code should reflect the answer to these questions.

Comment: Ideally, what is the place to install defaults before a view appears?

Comment: @DeepakSharma I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. You mean ideally for a clean architecture? Or just making it work in SwiftUI? Either way, try specifying your question and research the topic. Maybe this can help as a starting point https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/